# Cleaned trash, systems files deleted

Tags: home-directory

I deleted trash using `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` but along with trash the entire `/home` is deleted. Is there any way to recover? Even the backup `deja-dup` is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

That rm command does not delete your /home/.  You probably typed

```
sudo rm -rf ~/ .local/share/Trash/*`
```

See the space? Now that would delete your /home/$USER and the trash inside that directory too. And also a "deja-dup" back-up if it is stored in /home/$USER.

I would start of with a comment: there is never ever a reason for you to use that method to delete a trash. If you want to use "rm" that way you do

```
cd ~/.local/share/Trash
pwd
sudo rm -rf *
```

Examine the path that is shown after "pwd" and make sure it is correct and then you remove the files. You would have used a far more safer method.

> Even the backup deja-dup is deleted.

That file was not a backup if it was inside your /home. That file was a collection of files of your /home. You can only call it a backup if you move the file to an external medium away from your actual system.

> Is there any way to recover?

You restore a backup.

If you do not have a backup ...

- Your /home/ will be recreated after a reboot. If your personal files are of no interest you can then start using your system. Before you do read on ...
- Your personal files will not be recovered. If you want to attempt to recover the files that where once there: **do NOTHING to the partition or the disk**, create a backup of the partition or the whole disk with `dd`.

  You need to have the space to create a backup of the complete partition your /home is on or for the whole disk if you have no separate /home so use a very large USB disk for the "output" in that command ([Examples on this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/dd-command-examples/):`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` creates a dump of disk /dev/sda and puts that on /dev/sdb. Before using that command make sure you use the correct device names).

  After that you can use [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_FAQ) on the [image](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_FAQ#How_to_open_the_image.dd_file_.3F) you made or another recovery tool to examine the dump and try to recreate your /home/. Good luck with that ;)